# audio autoplay once only

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio

Simple call to player for 6 second clip works fine on main index page

```
<audio autoplay id="theme"><source src="sounds/theme.mp3"><source src="sounds/theme.ogg"></audio>
```

Have also added a simple button and associated java script to allow those who don't want the background music to turn it off.

```
<input type="button" id=musicbtn  class="btn" value="Stop da Music!" onclick="player(); change();">

<script> 
function player()
 {
  var player= document.getElementById("theme");
  if(player.paused) player.play();
  else player.pause(); 
 }  
function change() 
 {
  var elem = document.getElementById("musicbtn");
  if (elem.value=="Stop da Music!") elem.value = "Play da Music!";
  else elem.value = "Stop da Music!";
 }
```

All works as advertised, but looking for solution to have background music autoplay only the first time a visitor loads index.html. Subsequent visits autoplay should not function.

Suggestions? PHP, JS, etc are all acceptable solutions.

Have an ugly kludge in place involving navigation menu pointing to index2.html (which does not contain the audio tag) but not elegant, and a future pita. If you need to see further markup...
http://sailingofftheedge.com

Comment: Use a cookie. Check for a cookie on each visit. If it's there, don't autoplay. If it isn't, place the cookie and play the music. This won't work if your visitor has cookies turned off (but lots of other things will break then too.), and the EU has rules on how you can use cookies - you might need user consent for this.

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie with JavaScript's "`document.cookie`", and have your page test whether the cookie exists yet every time the user visits. If it does, you can `return;`, if not, you would set the cookie, then run the music.

Look at: [W3Schools Cookie Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for more info/tips.